# Two different sources return similar results on a specific field: which should I refer to?

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I have information extracted from two different sources.

`source 1` returns the following data

```
Name    Evaluation
A         50
B        100
C         57
D        212
E
```

`source 2` returns instead the following data

```
Name    Evaluation
A         51
B        100
C         57
D        240
E         28
```

I would like to ask you which criteria would allow me to select the most 'reliable' data and how to justify the choice. For instance, should I take the average of the values and rename as Evaluation including the error? Or should I consider the percentage of missing, if any, and go for the dataset which has less missing?

Has someone had any experience with managing a such situation?

Answer (score 2):

On the basis only of the two datasets, the question is unanswerable.

Presumably you want to do something with these data, e.g. predict some variable. For this purpose, the better source is the one with the better model.

"Reliable" is not an intrinsic property of either source. When you rely on it, you are relying on it for some purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot, chrishmorris. I would need just to assign these values to Name and use to plot them to see if exists a correlation with other variables in the dataset. The two sources use different algorithms to get those results so I would expect differences between the two datasets